# MySQL: Group most up-to-date result with the same id_type only

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` with a table which could contain more values with the same `id_type` like in this example:

```
table_intensity
id       id_type       value      user_id        creation_date
1        1             90.4       73             2010-11-06 16:27:32
2        4             1258       27             2010-11-06 16:27:48 <= up-to-date id_type
3        3              1.9       73             2010-11-06 16:31:02 <= up-to-date id_type
4        1             88.8       12             2010-11-06 16:33:11
5        1             89.1       12             2010-11-06 16:58:20 <= up-to-date id_type
```

How can I get the most up-to-date of every id_type? I thought something like this but dosen't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_intensity GROUP BY id_type ORDER BY id_type, creation_date
```

This to get a result like:

```
table_intensity
id       id_type       value      user_id        creation_date
2        4             1258       27             2010-11-06 16:27:48
3        3              1.9       73             2010-11-06 16:31:02
5        1             89.1       12             2010-11-06 16:58:20
```

Comment: I'm guessing you would need to also ORDER BY creation_date DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get your question correctly, this might work for what you want to do.
You can now use the `id` column if that is the PK to join to the result of the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_intensity A
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT id_type, MAX(creation_date) FROM table_intensity GROUP BY id_type) b
ON A.id_type = b.id_type
AND A.creation_date = b.creation_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by `id` rather than by `id_type`.

```
SELECT * FROM table_intensity GROUP BY id ORDER BY id_type, creation_date
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: There's even a tag for that here on stackoverflow: greatest-n-per-group